# Object destructuring syntax - ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I had been through array destructuring syntax, which is well understood.

What exactly are we doing below, when we say `var {p, q} = o;`?

Is `p` and `q` in `var {p, q}` different from properties of `o` i.e., `'p'` and `'q'`? If yes,

why `var {a, b} = o;` does not work?

```
> var o = {p: 42, q: true};
    undefined
> p
    ReferenceError: p is not defined
> q
    ReferenceError: q is not defined
> o['p']
    42
> o['q']
    true
> var {p, q} = o;
    undefined
> p
    42
> q
    true
> var {a, b} = o;
    undefined
> a
    undefined
> b
    undefined
```

*Note: I learnt that, dictionary keys are *string literals* in javascript.*

Comment: `var {p, q} = o;` === `var p = o.p;` and  `var q = o.q;` this will only work when the variables have the same name.

Comment: @Kitler Is this not a peculiar concept? Which programming language concept is derived to provide such facility? Is there any other language that does such weird stuff? I think destructuring is inspried from python

Comment: Weird is very subjective, it is a common pattern to assign values to attributes from an object where the name matches, this concept is taken from coffeescript iirc.

Comment: @Kitler variables have same name?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915621/object-destructuring-syntax-es6#comment51744549_31915693

Comment: The same name as the key on the object... It feels like you aren't even trying tbh, give [learn es 2015](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/) a read.

Comment: @Kitler same name as the key?  I am assuming term *identifier*, when you say *name*. BTW key is not identifer(`p`), but it is string literal `'p'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    var o = {p: 42, q: true};
     var {p, q} = o;
```

Here, `var {p,q} = o` is just a shorthand for  `var {p:p , q:q} = o`

Consider this.

```
      var o = { key : "value" };
      var { key : local_var } = o ;
      local_var === o["key"] // true
```

If you omit the local_var, and write
`var {key} = o;`
a new variable key will be created with the idenifier "key"., same like doing
`var key = o["key"]`

So in your example that's like doing

```
      var p =  o["p"] ;  //42
       var q = o["q"];   //true
       var a = o["a"];  // undefined
       var b = o["b"];   //undefined
```

This may not  be exactly true, but should help you understand it.
It's kind of something like Pattern Matching that other languages provide, but it's different.

Comment: `var o = {p: 42, q: true};` and then `var {a:var1, b:var2} = o;` this does not work. `'a'` and `'b'` , `'p'` and `'q'`are string literals.

Answer (score 6):

That's because using your syntax for object destructing, the names used in the LHS expression (`{a, b}`) are used as keys into the RHS expression (`o`). Since `a` and `b` are not properties of `o`, that fails (returns `undefined`).

The relevant section in the spec for this is in [Runtime Semantics: DestructingAssignmentEvaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-destructuringassignmentevaluation) under *AssignmentProperty : IdentifierReference Initializer* (2nd from last). AssignmentProperty are your `a` (and `b`... separately), and. The StringValue of `a`  is `'a'` and that is used as a key to get a value from `o` (equivalent `o['a']` in this case).

It would work if you'd do:

```
var {p:a, q:b} = o;
```

which uses *AssignmentProperty : PropertyName : AssignmentElement* (last entry) which uses a propery name (`p`) AND an assignment element (`a`).

Comment: See also http://es6-features.org/#ObjectMatchingDeepMatching, http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-destructuring-assignment.

Comment: `a` and `b` are identifiers. `p` and `q` are identifers in `var {p, q}`. But `'p'` and `'q'` are properties(keys) in dicitonary `o`, which are string primitve  literals. what do you mean by name matching?

Comment: `p` & `q` are properties of `o`. They can be referenced as string keys using the `object['key']` notation (`o['p']`), or through the `object.key` notation (`o.p`). In either case, that's unrelated to this issue. The global `p` & `q` variables play no part in this scenario.

Comment: @overexchange I think your are mixing up Python and JS syntax. In JS `{ a: b }` <=> `{ "a": b }`. The Python expression `{ a: b }` translates to `{ [a]: b }`.

Comment: @Kay Firstly Do you agree, if I say, key is *string literal* but not *identifier*(or name) in this syntax, `o = {p:1, q:2}.`? if you were to use the number `.12e3` as an (unquoted) property of dictionary, it would be coerced  into a string first, and the actual object key would become '120' . So,  when I say, `var obj = { .12e3: 'wut'};` then my key is `'120'` in memory,  `obj['120'];`

Comment: @overexchange, how is this related to your original question?

Comment: My previous comment is related to the answer which says *automatic name matching*. I don't know what *name* mean here?. here one is string literal `'p'` the other is identifier `p`. So, how would you match?

Comment: `var { .12e3: foo } = { .12e3: "foo" }; foo === "foo"` works as expected, and so does `var key = .12e3; var { [key]: foo } = { [key]: "foo" }; foo === "foo"`. There is nothing special here.

Comment: @Kay - Thanks for "taking over" while I was away :-).

Comment: @overexchange: FWIW, given `o = {p:1, q:2}`, there are no string literals here. `p` and `q` are actually *identifier names*. The object literal notation allows *string literals*, *number literals* and *identifier names* as "keys". ES6 also introduces *computed property names*. How something is expressed in syntax and represented in memory can differ. If you talk about "literals", then you talk about *syntax*, not runtime behavior.