# What is the effect of const object = this.variable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

I'm working on a react-native app which was initially developed by a remote company.
In this project I found the following code:

```
class SomeScreen extends Component {

  constructor {
    this.state = {
      connection: null
      codeInput: '',
      paramInput: '',
    }
  }

  someFunction() {
    const {
      connection,
      codeInput: code,
      paramInput: params,
    } = this.state
    this.otherFunction(connetion.var, parseInt(code), parseInt(params))
  }
}
```

I'm wondering what the `const {} = this.variable` does. I've never seen this way of assigning and I'm wondering if it's the same as

```
this.state.code = code;
this.state.params = params;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object destructuring syntax - ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915621/object-destructuring-syntax-es6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the code snippet below to understand your code. Basically you are just making a copy to a const variable.

```js
let obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
const {a} = obj;
console.log(a);
obj.a = 4;
console.log(obj.a);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: So if I understand right it's the opposite of what I supposed and the same as `const params = this.state.params; const code = this.state.code; const connection = this.state.connection;`

Comment: Yes, exactly. Assignment operator works right to left even in JS.

Comment: Thanks! So this piece of code has no effect whatsoever, just call the function without the needless assign (since it are strings and copied by value)

Answer (score 1):

It is Object Destructuring. Therewith you can unpack from values from arrays or properties from object. You can click link for more detailed information
[Object Destructuring Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)