# What does - "const { name } = require('something')" & "const name = require(something)()" mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, declaration

I have used variable declaration in JavaScript only as - `const name = require("something");`

1. But what does curly braces means in `const { name } = require('something')`. ?
2. And why some declaration have parentheses () in its end like- `const name = require('something')();` ?

What are the significance of both and where to use them while declaring variables?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object destructuring syntax - ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915621/object-destructuring-syntax-es6)

Comment: The first is called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), the second is requiring a function/class and calling/instanciating it right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const { name } = require('something')` is `destructuring` a `const` called name from whatever object is returned from the require statement.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Adding the parenthesis is going to execute whatever function is returned from the require statement