# What typeof searchParams Props for Typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-props, next.js13

I'm newbie at typescript and my codes:

```
type searchParamsProps = {
  manufacturer: string,
  model: string,
  year: number,
  fuel: string,
  limit: number,
}

export default async function Home({ searchParams }: searchParamsProps) {
  const allCars = await fetchCars({
    manufacturer: searchParams.manufacturer || "",
    model: searchParams.model || "",
    year: searchParams.year || 2022,
    fuel: searchParams.fuel || "",
    limit: searchParams.limit || 10,
  });
```

What is typeof of `searchParams`? I tried to describe the types with with `string`, `number`, or `union`, but how to type it correctly?

VSCode Intellisense says:

```
Property 'searchParams' does not exist on type 'searchParamsProps'.ts(2339)

(parameter) searchParams: any
```

Comment: This is a typo, your line should read: `export default async function Home({ searchParams }: { searchParams: searchParamsProps } ) {` or move the type definition of the props elsewhere or use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59988667/typescript-react-fcprops-confusion)

Comment: @Harrison Or instead of building an object just to destructure it: `Home(searchParams: searchParamsProps)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object destructuring syntax - ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915621/object-destructuring-syntax-es6)

Comment: @Harrison thanks for your advice, now typescript seem to be happy again.

Answer (score 0):

`{ ... } = foo` is a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) operation. When you do `{ searchParams }: searchParamsProps`, this means you want to extract the member called `searchParams` from `searchParamsProps`. However, `searchParamsProps` does not have a member called `searchParams`, therefore it does not have a type, since it doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the destructuring syntax of `searchParams` you could define the type of the parameter object as `{searchParams: searchParamsProps;}`.

```
export default async function Home({
  searchParams
}: {
  searchParams: searchParamsProps;
}) {
  const allCars = await fetchCars({
    manufacturer: searchParams.manufacturer || "",
    model: searchParams.model || "",
    year: searchParams.year || 2022,
    fuel: searchParams.fuel || "",
    limit: searchParams.limit || 10
  });
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhCGAnAxgCwApPgWwM7sQHsxcoBeKAbwFgAoKKbeAOwFcAzeZYVxCRAFxRcwRAEtmAcwDcdBtkIATCABshI8VNn0oIBIKhtsAI37aG7VqvWiJMuVBVjsY4EKOnE2gL7a6yQmYRKHYIYDQAYSRSCnhcEGZkKAAKADp0pElcIRYQAEpyAD4oADdCMUUoAAY-WggADzBCRGAoZU5WFVa4hKTLROAxQKgACUJsCGSaHVx9NExEHFw6byFphlmkeaw8ITgtjB38IhIfAvWoAKDulRUoxBioeAB3eFcQsMjoqYd5Fg4uDw%20AZNihDos8KkmGxONxePwoAAfRFQABEqIANL9GEprMI5uCllDcSokSj0VidAw9Eh1ASFkSaYgyVAAExVVmsykMCxWNT4g4MyGWVQsinYpwuNwCsFC3CpSXvZFQACMVQc3jyPiAA)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use generic types in Typescript: Reference [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

```
function identity<Type>(arg: Type): Type {
  return arg;
}
```